# ■ or ■+■ or ■+■+■ or ■+■+■+■

Tags: code-golf

### Sum of squares

Goal: Write a given natural number as sum of squares. Thanks to Lagrange, Fermat and Legendre we know that you can write any positive integer as sum of (one), two, three, or maximal four squares of integers.

Your task is to write a program/function which takes a natural number via stdin/argument and outputs/returns a list of one to four numbers, where the sum of the squares of those numbers equals the input number. But you have to find the shortest possible example, that means if you can write a number as three squares, you may not output the four squares version.

Examples:

```
1 : 1
2 : 1,1
3 : 1,1,1
4 : 2
5 : 1,2
6 : 1,1,2
127 : 1,3,6,9
163 : 1,9,9
1234 : 3,35
1248 : 8,20,28
```

Comment: I think this will have different answers from the other question because there's no time limit so brute force is possible.

Comment: Between the lack of a time constraint and the minimality of the number of squares I think it's borderline okay to keep, but I'm not sure what others think.

Comment: I just read the linked question in detail, (I did not find it before, because I was looking for 'sum of squares' and similar keywords), I'm gonna close this question if nobody opposes.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript: 141

```
function x(i){var a=0,b,c,d;for(;a<i;a++)for(b=0;b<i;b++)for(c=0;c<i;c++)for(d=0;d<i;d++)if(a*a+b*b+c*c+d*d==i){console.log(a,b,c,d);return}}
```

Comment: Your function does not return the 'shortest' example. E.g. for the input `11` your function returns `[0,1,1,3]` where the shortest answer would be `[1,1,3]`.

Comment: I assume the zeros returned don't count, as they don't contribute to the sum.

Comment: Does it always produce the shortest, ignoring 0s?

Comment: yes, by brute force.